# "An error occurred when fetching the tag editor"

Tags: discussion, editing, retagging

That is the message I get when want to edit the tags. Is there a general issue or just mine?

Comment: These posts seem related (both of them rather recent): [After clicking the "edit tags" link, a pop-up appears: "An error occurred when fetching the tag editor"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376282) (on [meta.se]) and [Edit tags not working and comment flag icon missing in Mobile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416088) (on Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: Just for the record, I will say the same thing [I said in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2022/2/20). I think that it is useful to have this bug report here - even if it has already been posted elsewhere (in some form). Many people are unaware of the sites I linked above - so if this isn't fixed soon, I would not be surprised to see another posts on this site about the same issue in the next few days.

Comment: Is the issue consistently reproducible on your end? I can bring up the tag editor  now

Comment: This kind of message appears (not so frequently but at least so often that I remember) when I have a temporary issue with my data connection on phone. Often switching off and on the data on phone fixes it. This kind of error is also seen when I try to post a comment.

Comment: Just for information: the posts [mentioned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34597/an-error-occurred-when-fetching-the-tag-editor#comment161164_34597) by Martin Sleziak have been marked [status-completed].